# Jython: remove a jar file from the classpath

Tags: jython

first question on stackoverflow so please be patient :)

I'm working on a Java project in which I need to add jar files at runtime. I use Jython since this way I'm able to easily find subclasses of a given class and a base package. No problem until now, since I just need to call

```
sys.path.append("myjarfilepath")
```

to see my new jar added to the classpath.

But how can I REMOVE a jar file from the classpath? Simply removing it from sys.path does not work. Removing the package from sys.modules does not work either.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Emanuele

Comment: Can elaborate on why you want to do that?

Comment: Because I want a GUI to load/unload plugins at runtime - without need to restart the application.

Comment: I just found a solution. It's an hack, but it works :) The first time that a PySystemState is instantiated, it is initialized. The initialization sets some static variables. I just needed a way to "reinitialize" PySystemState. I can do that with the reflection framework, forcing the "initialized" field to become false.